# WCF binding problems

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have problem with my bindings and i dont know how to solve it. I am on the server side and the client is using this binding:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" 
type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, 
Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
</httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="pciBinding" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" 
sendTimeout="00:05:00">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" 
writeEncoding="utf-8" />
      <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>

</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" 
type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, 
Microsoft.AI.Web"
    preCondition="managedHandler"/>
</modules>

<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

I put this also in my config file but the exception is still the same:
*The header 'Action' from the namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process.  Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding.*

What i need to do in order this to works?

Comment: please show your complete wcf configs for Server and Client side.

Comment: i have put my whole web.config file, but i don't have permission to see the client web.config file because it is an external application. the only thing i know from the guys is that i should use this binding.

Comment: Usually the server should dictate what binding should be used^^ As i can see, you have not a endpoint and bound your binding and behaviour on it. You need to add a endpoint like this `<endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="pciBinding" name="MyEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" contract="Your.Contract.Interface.With.Fullname" />` and you need to give you behaviour a name to bind it on the endpoint, in this example it's called "myBehavior".

Comment: thank you. i dont know how to mark your answer as correct..

Comment: Glad that it works. You can't mark comments as correct ;) I added my comment as answer and this can be marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a Endpoint to your config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service>
            <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="pciBinding" name="MyEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" contract="Your.Contract.Interface.With.Fullname" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and you need to give your behaviour a name to bind it on the endpoint, in this example it's called "myBehavior".